# Как проиграть файл скачанный с сервера swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, avfoundation

Я делаю аудио приложение часть аудио уже в приложении их я могу проиграть, но теперь проблема с проигрыванием аудио скачанным с сервера и хранящиеся в БД Realm записан как путь к файлу

> file:///Users/User/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/EE8A846B-  56D9-4B2B-9B52-FCC5CC16B7CA/data/Containers/Data/Application/C057C9A4-77DB-4615-AA78-C0A256ECD2D2/Documents/Dumont.mp3

Как его проиграть?

Answer (score 0):

Объявить плеер

```
let player:AVPlayer = AVPlayer()
```

скормить ему файл

```
let pathToFile = "тут ваш путь из базы"
player.replaceCurrentItem(with: AVPlayerItem(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: pathToFile)))
player.play()
```

Comment: Не помогло. Кстати до этого есть TableView откуда должны придти данные о выбранном треке

Comment: покажите как вы создаете плеер. и какую ошибку выдает AVPlayerItem